# Example for separable space that is not second countable

Tags: general-topology

Sir/madam,
How can I prove that the real line with semi open interval topology is separable but not second countable?

Thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: @YuiToCheng The titles may match, but this question is about proving that one specific space is separable but not second countable, whole your question is actually asking for a list of examples.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_Line_is_Separable and https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_Line_is_not_Second-Countable

Comment: @Arthur True, but the accepted answer there gives this example and proves it.

Comment: I think the most natural example is the set of all functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with the topology of pointwise convergence.

Comment: @bof that's a bit more work to show separable. I think Double Arrow and Sorgenfrey line are nicer in many ways. $\Bbb R^{\Bbb R}$ is not even normal.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I didn't say it was the easiest or the strongest or most useful example, just the most natural. It's a topological space someone might think about even if he wasn't looking for counterexamples.

Comment: @bof the pointwise topology is probably (outside general topology) the least used topology for that set though.